# Hook_menu_alter does not load correct page

Tags: users, routes

I'm trying to check if a user has permission(registered by a module) before he `adds/edits` fields on a node type registered by the module.

The approach is to use hook_menu_alter and add an access callback.

The URL i am trying to add this to is

```
admin/structure/types/manage/applx-application/fields
```

Where '`applx-application`' is the node type.

The problem is after the callback has been added via the hook, the page falls to
`admin/structure/types/` instead of a`dmin/structure/types/manage/applx-application/fields`

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Oh and `hook_menu_alter` is called by hook_hook_info. If that is of any concern.

```
    <?php
/*
    Implements hook_menu_alter
*/
function applx_menu_alter(&$items){
    $items['admin/structure/types/manage/applx-application/fields']['access callback'] = 'applx_permission_check';
    $items['admin/structure/types/manage/applx-application/fields']['access arguments'] = array('field_management');
}
```

My only guess is that it falls back to `structure/types` because the system module's menu hook expects a wildcard in place of **applx-application** i suppose.

What is the right way to do this, if not this way?

Answer (score -1):

Digging a little bit more i found out that the right way to do this is to use

hook_field_access

Comment: May you expand a little your answer? Saying you found another hook to use doesn't help future users, which is what Stack Exchange aims to do.